# Is it guaranteed that mnesia event listeners will get each state of a record, if it changes fast?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Let's say I have some record like `{my_table, Id, Value}`.
I constantly overwrite the value so that it holds consecutive integers like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.
In a distributed environment, is it guaranteed that my event listeners will receive all of the values? (I don't care about ordering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't verified this by reading that part of the source yet, but it appears that sending a message out is part of the update process, so messages should always come out, even on very fast changes. (The alternative would be for Mnesia to either queue messages or queue changes and run them in batches. I'm almost positive this is not what happens -- it would be too hard to predict the variability of advantageous moments to start batching jobs or queueing messages. Sending messages is generally much cheaper than making a change in the db.)

Since Erlang guarantees delivery of messages to a live destination this is as close to a promise that every Mnesia change will eventually be seen as you're likely to get. The order of messages couldn't be guaranteed on the receiving end (as it appears you expect), and of course a network failure could make a set of messages get missed (rendering the destination something other than live from the perspective of the sender).